# C# is this a bug or is this suppose to work this way?

Tags: c#-4.0

I was working on something else and came across this issue. Below is a basic sample. I belive that I shouldn't be able to access x or y.

```
public class Test
{
    private int x = 5;
    private int y = 10;

    public void TestBug()
    {
        Test test = new Test();
        // Why can I access x and y
        Console.WriteLine(test.x);
        Console.WriteLine(test.y);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test Sample = new Test();
        Sample.TestBug();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: No, that's the correct behaviour. Your code is inside `Test` and private variables are accessible to code in `Test`.

Comment: Thanks, sure seems odd that your able to access private variable of a instances of a class if it is within itself.

Comment: It's no different from capturing a variable in a local method or delegate. It's maybe unexpected, but it is consistent with the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's the correct behaviour. Your code is inside `Test` and private variables are accessible to code in `Test`.

It's no different from capturing a variable in a local method or delegate. It's maybe unexpected, but it is consistent with the language.

Try this code:

```
public class Test
{
    private int x = 5;
    private int y = 10;

    public void TestNotABug()
    {
        Test test = new Test();
        
        int z = 3;
        
        int Computation(int w)
        {
            return test.x + test.y + z + w;
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine(Computation(42));
    }
}
```

It outputs `60` as expected.

---

Here's a more concrete example of where you might use this feature:

```
public class Example : IEquatable<Example>
{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public bool Equals(Example other) =>
        this.x == other.x
        && this.y == other.y;
}
```

---

If you really want your mind blown, try this example:

```
void Main()
{
    var p = Person.Create("Satan", true);
    Console.WriteLine(p);
}

public abstract class Person
{
    private string _name;
    
    public static Person Create(string name, bool isEvil)
    {
        return isEvil ? new EvilPerson(name) : new EvilPerson(name);
    }
    
    protected Person(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    private class EvilPerson : Person
    {
        public EvilPerson(string name) : base(name) { }
        public override string ToString() => $"^^^{_name}^^^";
    }

    private class GoodPerson : Person
    {
        public GoodPerson(string name) : base(name) { }
        public override string ToString() => $"!!!{_name}!!!";
    }
}
```

That's accessing the private field of the parent class! It's in the right scope so it works.

This outputs `^^^Satan^^^`.

Comment: Thanks again. I found this while doing some game development. Both Players have a Health scripts and Player A can reference Player B’s instances and change private variables.

Comment: Your second example makes a lot more since. Thank you.

Comment: @JimS - Check out my third example.